# Shell Command to check whether the file is having today's date or not

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Can you please help me to check a file which is having current date or not.

Comment: Please show what you tried, and the specific error encountered, in the question. Also, your platforms tools matter, so your specific OS or distro should be specified -- in an ideal world you know you have GNU tools available and can use `stat`, `find -printf`, etc to directly extract the timestamp; [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087) is relevant. OTOH, if you're Linux-on-Android you might only have busybox tools available, which provides a much more constrained set of possible solutions.

Comment: I am looking for linux command. I tried with find command but i am not able to check the condition whether the file is with todays date or not

Comment: `find` really does work for the job. Show what you tried, and exactly how its output differs from what you want.

Comment: That said, as I said before, "Linux command" is not specific enough to be 100% sure of what will and will not work. The commands available on different Linux-based operating system distributions are not all identical.

Comment: what do you mean by "file which is having current date"? Is it the file *name*? the file *contents*? the file *last modified time*? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system:

```
find yourfile -maxdepth 0 -daystart -mtime -1 -print
```

...will only emit output if `yourfile` is newer than the beginning of the current day.